# Как определить javascript'ом, что на пользователь ничего не делает на странице?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Суть в следующем: хочется запускать анимацию на js, если пользователь, скажем, 2 минуты не производит никаких действий со страницей. Вот как определить, что он ничего не делает? :) Первое, что приходит в голову, поставить "таймер" на мышку. Есть еще идеи? :) Может кто уже что-то подобное делал?

Comment: Таймер на мышь и клавиатуру.

Comment: Есть готовый плагин для jQuery http://www.paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/